# Vue/TypeScript/Linting exclude .vue files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I have a Vue2 project which I am slowly converting to TypeScript.  My first phase is to go through the .js files, rename them to .ts and make sure they pass linting rules.

The issue is that when I run the build it is picking up all .vue files (as well .js files) and outputting with tons of linting errors.

How do I prevent the ts linting of non .ts files?

FYI - I have tried creating a brand new vue cli project and copying over the eslintrc, tsconfig, and relevant package.json sections to my project. However that does not fix the issue.  I have also tried setting the "include" section of the tsconfig file to only point to a single .ts file of mine that is bare-bones (has no imports and just exports a string).  However when I do a build it is still complaining about every .vue, .js etc file.

I'm not sure if this is related or a separate question but after this issue is resolved and I have converted all .js to .ts files I would need to start on the .vue files.  That would mean I would need to only target .vue files that have script lang=ts tags.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters given to `vue-cli-service lint` are passed through to ESLint, so you could pass the [`--ext` option](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--ext) to specify which file extensions to lint.

For instance, this `lint` NPM script lints only `.ts` files under `./src` and its subdirectories:

```js
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint ./src --ext .ts"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could run this directly from the command line, as `yarn` also passes through arguments to the underlying NPM script:

```sh
yarn lint ./src --ext .ts
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. Is It possible to use multiple linters in this scenario, such as a ts linter for ts and a regular one for js? Also, would this be able to be used to parse vue files and apply ts for when the script=ts tag is present? Thanks!